# Combine data on a mastersheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

As an MIS Coordinator on a daily basis I need to collect data to a mastersheet from 21 different files contained in a folder.  It is very time consuming to open every 21 files and copy daily data from each file and paste into mastersheet where previous day's work was pasted.  I do have one advantage that the 21 files have the same formatting so there is no need to cross-check every file.  I would appreciate any help, how can I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: I don't suppose you have any .NET developers in your office? Joking aside, this would be an easy piece of software to knock up for you. Sorry I can't be of any real help.

Comment: Consolidated Spreadsheet?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-HP010095249.aspx

Comment: do the file names change or are they consistent? in a common directory or where are they located? what do you want to do with the originals after you do this? move them or delete or something else?

Comment: Thanks all for your reply... here are few more details...1. File name will be same (eg. Countsheet - May 13 - User Name) only month will be change.  These files are saved on a commong shared folder containing only these files. Original files will be saved on daily basis by staff so they will remain as it is on drive (u can suggest other option)...

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started. It loops through a directory looking for excel files, opens them, copies a range from the target workbook, pastes it to the master workbook and then closes the target workbook without saving.

```
Sub CopyFiles()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir("C:\folder\*.xls")
Dim wbdata As Workbook
Dim wbtarget As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Set wbdata = ActiveWorkbook


    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set wbtarget = Workbooks.Open(StrFile)

            'Your operation here
            wbtarget.Range("A1:C1").Copy
            wbdata.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            i = i + 1
            wbtarget.Close savechanges:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```